# How to build a list with starting and ending columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

So I have a huge list of data I need to update in SQL. I am do the modifying in Excel to get it into lists to make it easier to update. What I have is a Starting Bin, Ending Bin, and a range they might be in A-D. What I want to do is create a list where it goes 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, then repeat to 2 thru 10. Then have it go 11A, 11B, 11C, thru 15. In this given example. Is there a way to do it? Right now I am doing a concat with multiple columns and it is getting cumbersome. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You can try using `Power Query`

Comment: Can you show the expected output you need. I can try with Power Query. I have tried using Power Query, Can you confirm from the image [Check](https://imgur.com/gallery/FkQ3cE2)

Comment: That is close to what I am looking for. If I could get them to show up on separate rows would be preferred but if they are all in the same text box then I could easily split the cell based on a comma. Can you show me how you did that?

Comment: I have just posted the solution in answers, please check and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this task using **Power Query** please follow the steps,

[image]

---

• Select some cell in your **Data Table**,

• **Data Tab** => **Get&Transform** => **From Table/Range**,

• When the **PQ Editor** opens: **Home** => **Advanced Editor**,

• Make note of all the **2 Tables Names** (Initial Table Name - **Querytbl**, After Importing From PQ Editor - **Outputtbl**),

• Paste the `M Code` below in place of what you see.

• And refer the notes

---

```
let
    //Source Data
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Querytbl"]}[Content],

    //Adding Custom Column To Create A List Of Starting Bay and Ending Bay
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each {[Starting Bay]..[Ending Bay]}),

    //Adding Custom Column To Create A List Of Numbers From Starting Level and Ending Level,    
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each {Character.ToNumber([Starting Level])..Character.ToNumber([Ending Level])}),

    //Expanding The First Custom Column,
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom"),

    //Expanding The Second Custom Column,
    #"Expanded Custom.1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "Custom.1"),

    //Adding Custom Column To Convert The Numbers In Second Column To Alphabets,
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom.1", "Custom.2", each Character.FromNumber([Custom.1])),

    //Removing Unwanted Column(s)
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Custom.1"}),

    //Duplicating The First Custom Column
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", "Custom - Copy"),

    //Merging Both The Custom Columns Without Any Delimiter,
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Duplicated Column", {{"Custom - Copy", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Custom - Copy", "Custom.2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),

    //Grouping Rows Based On Starting & Ending Bay, Starting & Ending Level and Custom,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Merged Columns", {"Starting Bay", "Ending Bay", "Starting Level", "Ending Level", "Custom"}, {{"All", each Text.Combine([Merged],","), type text}}),

    //Removed Column Custom
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Custom"}),

    //Grouping Again Based On Starting & Ending Bay, Starting & Ending Level
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns1", {"Starting Bay", "Ending Bay", "Starting Level", "Ending Level"}, {{"All", each Text.Combine([All],"#(lf)"), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows1"
```

---

This is the output you will get to see in the PQ Editor,

[image]

---

• Finally select the one load it into your worksheet, and finish task: Click On **Home** Tab In PQ Editor --> **Close & Load** --> **Close & Load To** --> Select either **Existing worksheet**: with the respective cell reference where you want to place or the **New Worksheet**

[image]

---

In Excel you will see this

[image]

---

EDIT --> updated as per OP's working file.

[image]

---

Comment: So when I tried that I got an error. It doesn't look like all the bins are that easy with the names. 
I got this error:
Expression.Error: The value isn't a single-character string.
Details:
    Value=G145

Comment: @amcclay can you share a copy of the excel workbook using one-drive cloud storage link. because i cant see the error which you are getting and why you are getting that error, may be based on the data you have but the solution posted based on the explanation of your post

Comment: Here you go. The data is on Table2 and Multi Sku Mattoon tabs
https://ruralkingsupply-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/amcclay_ruralking_com/EcqG95DzvT9GlqiBhX0rR0sB_QWrdFE86aGSm4SMPLGVMg?e=t47uAM

Comment: @amcclay alright give me sometime

Comment: Hi Sir, are you there, there is one problem with your data, because earlier it was numbers in Starting Bay and Ending Bay while in your Data those are alphanumeric, we might need to add an extra step

Comment: @amcclay sir can you confirm if the ending level is null what should be taken that as?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Yes but what should take that? Should it be same as starting level

Comment: @amcclay Sir, can you check once this is the file link and its editable. [Link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cijQ62CFy9okRMssG?e=NJtFcC) and confirm me please

Comment: Yeah It is editable but it doesn't look like the letters in the bin names are coming thru.

Comment: @amcclay Sir sorry for the delay my internet is slow. I am updating a screenshot please check. You have to refresh the table. [Link](https://imgur.com/gallery/cLH2vn7)

Comment: No problem but the letters at the beginning of the bins is missing.

Comment: @amcclay Sir, updated [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cijQnIL2KQd2nuO4X?e=yKkB4u)

Comment: That works. Can you share how you did that? I tried to sign in but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: @amcclay Sir you need to download the file. and refresh the table. The steps are same as mentioned above, also if you want to see the updated m-code then when you select any cell on the greyeish table, you will see in the ribbon tab a new tab will appear, `Query` tab on selecting you will see `Edit` option, on clicking it opens the PQ Editor. from home tab, advance editor to view the code.